# UWP AdvancedCollectionView filter not working with strings

Tags: c#, listview, filter, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I have a **AdvancedCollectionView** from **Windows Community Toolkit** version **6.1.1** and trying to use it to filter out on 2 string properties.

I have created a simple app to reproduce the issue : https://github.com/touseefbsb/UWP-Filter-List

It has a textbox for filtering between **StartNumber** and **EndNumber** properties of items.

[image: MainPage]

but as soon as I enter text "123" into it, it shows no item in the ListView when it should actually show only the first item, based on the test logic.

[image: Filter image]

### Code

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox
        x:Name="SearchTicketBooksBox"
        Width="300"
        Header="Search"
        TextChanged="SearchTicketBooks_TextChanged" />
    <ListView
        x:Name="TicketBooksListView"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="4,0,0,0"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.TicketBooks}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="app1:TicketBookDto">
                <StackPanel Margin="20">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind StartNumber}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind EndNumber}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; }
    public MainPage() { InitializeComponent(); ViewModel = new MainViewModel(); }

    private void SearchTicketBooks_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewModel != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchTicketBooksBox.Text))
            {
                ViewModel.TicketBooks.Filter = _ => true;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewModel.TicketBooks.Filter = x => ((TicketBookDto)x).StartNumber == SearchTicketBooksBox.Text;
                //{
                //    var startNumber = Convert.ToInt32(((TicketBookDto)x).StartNumber);
                //    var endNumber = Convert.ToInt32(((TicketBookDto)x).EndNumber);
                //    var searchText = Convert.ToInt32(SearchTicketBooksBox.Text);
                //    return searchText >= startNumber && searchText <= endNumber;
                //};
            }
        }
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.TicketBooks.Add(new TicketBookDto { StartNumber = "123", EndNumber = "456" });
        ViewModel.TicketBooks.Add(new TicketBookDto { StartNumber = "789", EndNumber = "987" });
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TicketBookDto> _ticketBooksPrivate = new ObservableCollection<TicketBookDto>();
    private AdvancedCollectionView ticketBooks;
    public AdvancedCollectionView TicketBooks
    {
        get
        {
            if (ticketBooks is null)
            {
                ticketBooks = new AdvancedCollectionView(_ticketBooksPrivate, true);
                ticketBooks.ObserveFilterProperty(nameof(TicketBookDto.StartNumber));
                ticketBooks.ObserveFilterProperty(nameof(TicketBookDto.EndNumber));
            }
            return ticketBooks;
        }
        set => Set(ref ticketBooks, value);
    }

    #region INotifyStuff
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    #endregion
}
```

**TicketBookDto**

```
public partial class TicketBookDto
{
    public string StartNumber { get; set; }
    public string EndNumber { get; set; }
}
```

> I have commented out code of the actual logic I need in the filter, which is to show the list items only those who have the search number between their "StartNumber" and "EndNumber" properties. But for simplicity I am using a simple match to StartNumber logic to find out why it aint working. Also when I add a boolean property and simply filter using that property then it works fine, its just not working with these string properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't use `Filter` in `TextChanged` event,  please refer the source code [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/76a5fd96fa097795265b44f426ec95d98c681369/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/AdvancedCollectionView/AdvancedCollectionView.cs#L539).

```
if (_filter != null)
        {
            for (var index = 0; index < _view.Count; index++)
            {
                var item = _view.ElementAt(index);
                if (_filter(item))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                RemoveFromView(index, item);
                index--;
            }
        }
```

When you input text in the *SerchBox* and if the text is not equal to the filter property, the item will be `RemoveFromView`. So it will make the next input not effect.  For this design, we suggest you make submit button to filter the data after finished input.

**And If you do want to filter** in the `TextChanged`, you could call  `ViewModel.TicketBooks.Filter = _ => true;` to reset the viewtiems before set  `Filter` delegate method like the following.

```
private void SearchTicketBooks_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (ViewModel != null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchTicketBooksBox.Text))
        {
            ViewModel.TicketBooks.Filter = _ => true;
        }
        else
        {    // reset the filter
            ViewModel.TicketBooks.Filter = _ => true;
            ViewModel.TicketBooks.Filter = x => ((TicketBookDto)x).EndNumber == SearchTicketBooksBox.Text;

        }
    }
}
```